# Matlab inverse issue - fmri data - partial correlation algorithm

Tags: matlab, partial, correlation, inverse

I'm using the following code To get a partial correlation matrix (original code from http://www.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/analysis/netsim/)

```
ic=-inv(cov(ts1)); % raw negative inverse covariance matrix
r=(ic ./ repmat(sqrt(diag(ic)),1,Nnodes)) ./ repmat(sqrt(diag(ic))',Nnodes,1); % use diagonal to get normalised coefficients
r=r+eye(Nnodes); % remove diagonal
```

My original matrix (ts1) is a brain activity over time course (X variable) in multiple voxels -volumetric pixel 3X3 (Y variable).

The problem is, I have more dependent variables(y -voxels  ) than independent variables(x - time course).
I get the following Warning-

Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled.
         Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 4.998365e-022.

Any thoughts on how to fix the code so I'll get the partial correlation between all of the voxels?

Comment: You should do some cursory reading on linear algebra, in order to understand this warning: [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) vs. [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

The warning is from Matlab having a problem inverting the covariance matrix.

One solution might be to try pinv()
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pinv.html